# Trusted notebook database: where is it

Tags: dynamic, notebooks, files-and-directories

I've just moved to a new institution where the site licence comes with a custom version of mathematica 11.0.0. On my mac, I've cleaned up by removing `~/Library/Mathematica`, and "com.wolfram.Mathematica.plist" in preferences folder.

However, now all dynamical notebooks, including the about... dialogue, and all documentation pages shows a banner that displays the banner that says potentially unsafe dynamic content.

I've noticed for example, for the "Plot" help page, that if I click enable, the dynamic part are displayed, and it no longer display the dynamic warning for "Plot" after quitting and reopening the app.

However, for another page, say, "PlotRange", the warning comes again. Removing the `~/Library/Mathematica` folder and "com.wolfram.Mathematica.plist" preference, and the dynamic warning for "Plot" still displays ok without warning. Therefore, it makes logical sense that the data that says the "Plot" page is trusted is not in `~/Library/Mathematica` or the preference plist file.

I've edited the "Trusted path" to root and removed all untrusted path, and enabled trust by default, but the dynamic warning still comes up. Maybe it's a bug but since it's a custom version site licence which only gives 11.0.0, I cannot update to the newest version.

**In general, where is the infomation that says the "Enable" button has been clicked for a notebook kept on mac?**

The documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html) is not helpful, I've done all in it to no avail.

Comment: See `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {"NotebookSecurityOptions","TrustedPath"}]`. Of if you have a notebook by name already, try ``FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath[notebookName, "NotebookSecurityOptionsTrustedPath"]``. If it's on the trusted path, that should find it (although you may need to drop add some stuff to the path, see, e.g. ``FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["Documentation/English", 
  "NotebookSecurityOptionsTrustedPath"]`` vs ``FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["English", 
  "NotebookSecurityOptionsTrustedPath"]``).

Comment: I've enabled trusted path or all and deleted all untrusted paths, and enabled trust by default, but they do not help. Just figured that out: on macos, the culprit is the extended attribute `com.apple.quarantine` for the documentation notebooks. Fixed by `xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine` on Mathematica.app